# Cartesian product of compact sets is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, product-space

Prove that if two sets $A$ and $B$ are compact then so is their Cartesian product $A \times B = \{(a,b): a \in A, b\in B\}$.

The hint is to use Bolzano Weiertrass theorem and an argument of sequence to proof the statement.

Comment: Yes, the hint is good. Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: To avoid the axiom of countable choice or other (mostly stronger) choice principles, this is usually done using the tube lemma.

Comment: In the general case, this is known as Tychonoff's Theorem.

Comment: The OP does not say whether they are interested in a proof of this fact for metric spaces or (more generally) for topological spaces. But since Bolzano-Weierstrass is mentioned in the question, it is possible that the question is supposed to be only about $\mathbb R^n$?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A set $S$ is compact if from any sequence of elements in $S$ you can extract a sub-sequence with a limit in $S$.

If we are given a sequence $(u_n)$ of $A \times B$, then you can write $u_n=(a_n,b_n)$. Since $A$ is compact, you can find a sub-sequence $(a_{f(n)})$ with a limit in $A$. Then, since B is also compact, you can extract a sub-sequence $(b_{f(g(n))})$ of $(b_{f(n)})$ with a limit in B. Thus, the sub-sequence $(u_{f(g(n))})$ of $(u_n)$ has its limit in $A \times B$. This proves that $A \times B$ is compact.

I hope that you can understand my explanation, as I am still learning English.

Comment: This is not correct, at least as the question is asked. Generally speaking, compactness does not imply sequential compactness and sequential compactness doesn't imply compactness.

Comment: @MathsWizzard But the question was asked under the [metric-spaces] tag and made reference to Bolzano-Weierstrass, suggesting the author only asked the question in the context of metric (or more likely, just Euclidean) space. So this is perfectly fine

Answer (score 54):

There is indeed a topological proof using the open covers definition of compactness.

Let $A$ and $B$ be compact sets and $\{O_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be an open cover of $A \times B$. For each $(a,b) \in A \times B$, we can choose some $\lambda = \lambda(a,b)$ such that $(a,b) \in O_{\lambda(a,b)}$. By construction, $O_{\lambda(a,b)}$ is open, hence the point $(a,b)$ is contained in some open box $X \subset O_{\lambda(a,b)}$ where $X = U_{(a,b)} \times V_{(a,b)}$, where $U_{(a,b)} \subset A$ and $V_{(a,b)} \subset B$.

Suppose we fix $a$ and vary $b$. Then for every point $(a,b)$ we find that the point is contained in an open box in the product $A \times B$, and that box is then itself the product of a subset of $A$ with a subset of $B$. Proceeding in this manner, we observe that the collection of sets $\{V_{(a,b)}\}_{b\in B}$ is an open cover of $B$. Since by assumption $B$ is compact, we can find a finite cover $\{V_{(a,b_j(a))}\}$ of $B$ that consists of finitely many open sets containing points $\{(a,b_j(a))\}$.

Now let $U_a = \bigcap_j U_{(a,b_j(a))}$. Since $U_a$ is the intersection of finitely many open sets, it is itself open. Since $A$ is compact, there are finitely many $a_i$ such that $\{U_{a_i}\}$ forms an open cover of $A$. Then it follows that the collection of sets $\{O_{(a_i,b_j(a_i))}\}$ (for all combinations of $i,j$) is a finite cover of $A \times B$, hence $A \times B$ is compact.

Comment: How does it follow that $\{U_{a_i}\}$ covers $A$? Couldn't $U_a$ be an empty set?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist $a\in U_a$.

Comment: Might be a silly question... Given $(a, b)$ is in some open set $O_{\lambda(a, b)}$, why can you claim that $(a, b)$ is contained in some open box $U_{(a, b)} \times V_{(a, b)}$?

Comment: @DerekPan because rectangles constitute to a basis of the product topology

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\{V_{(a,b)}\}_{b \in B} $ is not a cover of $B$. But it is a cover of $\{a\}\times B$ which is homeomorphic to $B$, and hence compact.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof is adapted from Munkres' *Topology* (page 167), and it works for topological spaces, too. We shall use the following claim, which is important in its own right:

**Lemma (The tube lemma).** Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, $Y$ is compact, and $x_0\in X$. If $N$ is an open set of $X\times Y$ such that $\{x_0\}\times Y\subseteq N$, then there is an open neighbourhood $W$ of $x_0$ in $X$ such that $\{x_0\}\times Y\subseteq W\times Y\subseteq N$. (The set $W\times Y$ is often called a *tube* about $x_0\times Y$.)

The proof of the tube lemma is given in Munkres.

**Theorem.** If $X$ and $Y$ are compact topological spaces, then $X\times Y$ is compact.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal A$ be an open cover of $X\times Y$, and let $x_0\in X$. The "slice" $\{x_0\}\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, and so it is compact. Since $\mathcal A$ is also an open cover of $\{x_0\}\times Y$, there are sets $A_1,\dots,A_m\in\mathcal A$ such that $\{x_0\}\times Y\subseteq A_1\cup\dots\cup A_m$. Applying the tube lemma with $N=A_1\cup\dots\cup A_m$, we obtain an open neighbourhood $W$ of $x_0$ such that $\{x_0\}\times Y\subseteq W\times Y\subseteq A_1\cup\dots\cup A_m$. We have thus established the following claim:

> For every $x\in X$, there is an open neighbourhood $W_x$ of $x$ such that $W_x\times Y$ can be covered by finitely many sets in $\mathcal A$.

The remainder of the proof is easy. Since $\mathcal W=\{W_x:x\in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$, by the compactness of $X$ there are finitely many sets $W_1,\dots,W_n\in\mathcal W$ such that $X=W_1\cup\dots\cup W_n$. The union of the sets $W_1\times Y,\dots,W_n\times Y$ is $X\times Y$, and as each $W_i\times Y$ can be covered by finitely many sets in $\mathcal A$, the whole of $X\times Y$ admits a finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathscr{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $X\times Y$, then each projection $\pi_1\mathscr{U}$ and $\pi_2\mathscr{U}$ converges to at least one point $x\in X$ and at least one point $y\in Y$, respectively, since these spaces are compact. It is then easy to see that $\mathscr{U}$ converges to $(x,y)$; neighbourhoods of $(x,y)$ necessarily contain sets of form $V\times W$ where $V,W$ are open neighbourhoods of $x,y$ and these are contained in $\pi_{1,2}\mathscr{U}$, respectively, by definition of convergence; in other words, both $V\times Y$ and $X\times W$ are elements of $\mathscr{U}$ thus their finite intersection $V\times W$ is also in $\mathscr{U}$; therefore the original neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ is an element of $\mathscr{U}$, using the axioms of a filter.

Because we have established every ultrafilter on $X\times Y$ is convergent, it follows $X\times Y$ is compact. This generalises, almost verbatim, to a proof of the general Tychonoff theorem that any product of compact spaces is compact.