# If A and B are compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $A\times B$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, compactness

**Lemma:** If A and B are compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $A\times B$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**Proof:** let V={$V_{\alpha}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 |\alpha \in I$} is an open cover of $A\times B$. So, $A\times B \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} V_{\alpha}$. $A$ and $B$ $\subseteq A \times B \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} V_{\alpha}$, since $A\times${0} and $B\times${0} are equal to $A$ and $B$. Thus, V is also an open cover of $A$ and $B$. Since $A$ and $B$ are compact, there exist some finite subcover of V i.e. $A\subseteq V_{n_1} \bigcup ..... \bigcup V_{n_k}$ and $B \subseteq V_{m_1} \bigcup ..... \bigcup V_{m_l}$, where $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $A \times B \subseteq V_{n_1} \bigcup ..... \bigcup V_{n_k} \bigcup V_{m_1} \bigcup ..... \bigcup V_{m_l}$. Which is a finite subcover of V.

Is my proof correct and satisfactory? Can this lemma be generalize to metric space?

Comment: An open set in $\mathbb R^{2}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb R$, so $V$ cannot be an open cover for $A$. Also, $A \times \{0\} \neq A$.

Comment: You are indexing your cover by $A$ but $A$ is already being used for something else.

Comment: If you are aware of the description of compact subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ (closed + bounded), then you can use that for a much easier proof.

Comment: About the generalization: the product of any compact topological spaces is always compact.

Comment: $B$ and $B\times \{0\}$ are not equal. it would be advantageous to write each $V_{\alpha}$ as $U_{\alpha}\times W_{\alpha}$ for open sets $U_{\alpha}$ and $W_{\alpha}$.

Comment: @Berci non-trivial problem when you start producting infinitely many topological spaces

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I used my 220 IQ. My motivation for that was theorem 1.26.

Comment: @CSquared I guess similar answer is given in this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2018473/861687 ,but I don’t understand some notation and terminology like $U_y(x)$, open box neighbourhood, $N_{x}$ etc. can you please help with that?