# Exercise 11, Section 17 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Show that a product of two Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff.

I rephrase this exercise to my taste.

> If $(X,\mathcal{T}_{X})$ &  $(Y,\mathcal{T}_{Y})$ are Hausdorff space, then $(X\times Y,\mathcal{T}_{p})$ is Hausdorff.

**My attempt:** let $\mathcal{B}=\{ U\times V| U\in \mathcal{T}_X, V\in \mathcal{T}_Y \}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{T}_{p}$. Let $x\times y, p\times q \in X\times Y$ such that $x\times y\neq  p\times q$. Which implies $x\neq p$ or $y\neq q$. If $x \neq p$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, $\exists M, N \in \mathcal{T}_X$ such that $x\in M$, $p\in N$ and $M \cap N= \phi$. So $M\times Y,N\times Y \in \mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_{p}$ with $x\times y \in M \times Y$ and $p\times q \in N \times Y$. We have $(M \times Y) \cap (N \times Y)=(M \cap N) \times Y=\phi \times Y=\phi$. If $y\neq q$. Proof is similar. **Is this proof correct?**

Is there rigorous way to prove $\phi \times \phi =\phi$?

Comment: It is possible for $x \times y \ne p \times q$ and $x=p$ to both hold; you need to consider these cases.

Comment: @angryavian ohhh... I completely forgot that possibility.

Comment: @angryavian Is $\phi \times A=\phi$, $A$ is non empty set?

Comment: $A\times \emptyset =\emptyset$ simply because there is no $a\in A, b\in \emptyset $ such that $(a,b)\in A\times \emptyset.$

Comment: @Matematleta Is that proof rigorous enough?

Comment: @Matematleta In one of my post (link: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4286714/861687), set of two tuples is not a subset of set of one tuple.