# Show that the set $[0,1]×[0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to standard metric

Tags: analysis, compactness

I have to show that the set $[0,1]×[0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the standard metric.

I have to show this using only the definition of compactness. The definition I am given is: A set is compact if we have an open cover, we get a finite subcover.

Comment: cf. page 39 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (third edition)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartesian product of compact sets is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567335/cartesian-product-of-compact-sets-is-compact)

Answer (score 4):

Heine-Borel Theorem states that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, and your subset is certainly closed and bounded

Comment: The proof given on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) is quite elegant and directly applicable to the question here.

Comment: hello i have to show it with my definition with open cover and a finite subcover

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^\infty $ a cover of open set of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. Since $U_i$ is open, there are open cubes $(a_j^i,b_j^i)\times (a_j^i,b_j^i)$ s.t. $$U_i=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (a_j^i,b_j^i)\times (a_j^i,b_j^i).$$

Therefore $(a_j^i,b_j^i)_{i,j=1}^{\infty }$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$. Therefore, there is a subcover (denoted $\{(a_j^i,b_j^i)\}_{\substack{i=1,...,n\\ j=1,...,m}}$) of $[0,1]$. Therefore $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a finite subcover of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: i think this is the correct proof because you use my definition, but i never had cubes in my math course.

Comment: what are open cubes? open sets? i never had that

Comment: @sarahmathmatics67: open cube in $\mathbb R^2$ is a set of the form $(a,b)\times (a,b)$

Comment: is it another name for cartesian product?

Comment: no. $(1,2)\times (1,2)$ is a cube whereas $(1,2)\times (1,3)$ is not (the latter is call an open rectangle).

Comment: ok thanks i understand! can i let the word out for the proof? because i never learned it

Comment: sure :) (just right : "there are sets of the form..." instead of "there are cubes of the form...")

Comment: ok thaaanks :))

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

Every closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact.

The product of finitely many compact spaces is compact.

Comment: This is not true. Closed, *bounded* intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are compact.

Comment: Topology, Corrolary 27.2., J. Munkres (2nd Edition)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be available online, @Anton Vrdoljak. $[0, \infty)$ is trivially not compact, using the open cover $\{ (n - 2, n + 2) | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I think by closed interval he means an interval of the form $[a, b]$ where $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Botond While that may be true, that's not the canonical definition of a closed interval, and that definition is particularly relevant for someone studying topology.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I think it is when you are not dealing with topology (for example, in "early" analysis), and in topology, you can either keep it or modify it.

Comment: A real interval is a convex set, i.e. a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so that for any numbers $a,b \in I$, all numbers $c$ satisfying $a < c < b$, we have $c \in I$. Note that this does not in any way exclude unbounded intervals.

Comment: To @Alexander Geldhof: because the limit in the number of characters for a comment, I am not able to write in more details what is (according to Munkres) closed interval in $X$, where $X$ is a simply ordered set...

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/368108/721644). Such a statement couldn't possibly get 55 upvotes if it were inaccurate. Every closed interval in $\Bbb R$ is bounded, at least that is what they teach us in Croatia, so this can be a _weaker_ , but not a _false_ statement. Furthermore, there is some [available literature](https://www.google.com/url?url=https://support.google.com/websearch?p%3Dfeatured_snippets%26hl%3Den-HR&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&usg=AOvVaw3ls5QWloySVe215MPrfqR5&hl=en-HR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirrvHNkofqAhVVr4sKHYT0B-EQrpwBegQIChAP).

Comment: As a matter of a fact, we even put the accent by calling it a _segment_.